# MS Access DatePart("m", [date]) by date name

Tags: ms-access, criteria

Is there a way to create a criteria in Ms Access to get all data from a date/time column by a specific (user input) month and a year.

I need to do something like the following:

```
Like "* " & DatePart("m", [date]) = "aug" AND DatePart("yyyy", [date]) = 2017
```

and then all data in the table that have the month and year show up.

Thank you for all the help. 
I solved it by the following:

```
DatePart("m",[date])=Month(DateValue(Left([Month],3) & "-01-2017")) And DatePart("yyyy",[date])=[year]
```

PS. [date] is the column that has the date/time data and [month], [year] are what the user is prompted to enter.

So the user is asked for a month: She can input: Aug or aug or August and it will get the month as an integer.

Comment: Well it returns the number so `DatePart("m", [date]) = 8` (`monthname(datepart("m", date)) = "August"` as well, an additional `, True` to `monthname` makes it use abbreviations)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Format` instead of `DatePart`:

```
Like "* " & Format([date], "mmm") = "Aug" AND DatePart("yyyy", [date]) = 2017
```

Note that it's "Aug" not "aug", if you really have to use "aug" then this will do:

```
Like "* " & LCase(Format([date], "mmm")) = "aug" AND DatePart("yyyy", [date]) = 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never handle dates like strings, nor numbers, no exceptions.

So convert your text entries to date values and an create an interval:

```
>=CDate([Enter Month] & Str([Enter Year])) And <DateAdd("m",1,CDate([Enter Month] & Str([Enter Year])))
```

Do specify in your query the month and year parameters as text and integer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help. I solved it by the following:

```
DatePart("m",[date])=Month(DateValue(Left([Month],3) & "-01-2017")) And DatePart("yyyy",[date])=[year]
```

PS. [date] is the column that has the date/time data and [month], [year] are what the user is prompted to enter.

So the user is asked for a month: She can input: Aug or aug or August and it will get the month as an integer.